# mysql need get count of dependencies of other table

Tags: mysql

have 2 tables:

```
`contactslistrelations`

(`id`, `contactid`, `contactlistid`)
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1),
(4, 4, 1),
(5, 5, 1),
(6, 6, 1),
```

and another one:

```
`contacts`

(`id`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `unsubscribed`)
(1, "name1", "surname1", "email1", "0"),
(2, "name1", "surname2", "email1", "0"),
(3, "name1", "surname3", "email1", "0"),
(4, "name1", "surname4", "email1", "1"),
(5, "name1", "surname5", "email1", "0"),
(6, "name1", "surname6", "email1", "0"),
```

And I need to get count from `contactlistrelations` table of contacts which is not `unsubscribed` in `contacts` table

Comment: What have you tried.  The answer to this is elementary, so it seems like you have not attempted to solve this before asking for help here.

Comment: i have tried some different ways with sub-select query, but it's not working,

Comment: What would be the expected result from the given example set ?

Comment: need just count of contacts in contactslistrelations where contact is not unsubscribed in contacts table.

Comment: So in this case its 5 ?

Comment: yup.. :) bu I get the result in the first answer comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) like this, which should return the number of people on each contactList which isn't unsubscribed

```
Select contactlistrelations .contactlistid,count(*) AS count 
  FROM contactlistrelations 
  JOIN contacts on contacts.id = contactlistrelations.contactid 
  WHERE contacts.unsubscribed = 0
  GROUP BY contactlistrelations.contactlistid
```

Comment: with some modifications I get what I need.. :) thanks for showing me the way :) my query: 
 `Select count(*) AS count FROM contactlistrelations JOIN contacts on contacts.id = contactlistrelations.contactid WHERE unsubscribed = 0 AND contactlistrelations .contactlistid = 1`

Comment: Ahh i just thourght you wanted to be able to get every contactListId (the reason behind the group by).
But you are welcome :)

Comment: Yeah.. I understood that :) so I corrected to my self.. :) BIIIG thanks :D